# Transactions on multiple connection, data integrity fails while one transaction executes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions, data-integrity

I am trying to work on a transaction based PHP-MYSqli with OOPS code for a small application in the following scenario:

*PHP 5.6.x* for server and PHP Desktop version *phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3*, thus application will run both on 5.6.x and 7.x versions of PHP.

> Multiple people can access the same php application simultaneously. This means that every user will have an independent connection available to access the application because I have included a connection on the top of every page through files inclusion. What I want is that when one user presses the submit button, all the tables inside a particular transaction should get locked in read and write mode and none of them should be accessible by any of the users on the same or any other connection. Thus, I want 100% data integrity.

I have written the following two files:

**p1.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "jag_db");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
    //$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
    $i=0;
    $val2="Kurukshetra";
    for($i=100;$i<=50000;$i++)
    {
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO transtest (roll,city) VALUES(?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $i, $val2);
        if(!$stmt->execute())
        {
            $mysqli->rollback();
            exit;
        }
    }
    $sql20=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM transtest");
    $sql20->execute();
    $result20=$sql20->get_result();
    if($result20->num_rows>0)
    {
        while($rows20=$result20->fetch_object())
        {
            $sno=$rows20->sno;
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("UPDATE transtest SET city=? WHERE sno=?");
            if($sno%2==0)
                $city="Ambala";
            else
                $city="Kaithal";
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $city, $sno);
            if(!$stmt->execute())
            {
                $mysqli->rollback();
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $mysqli->rollback();
        exit;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->commit();
    $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="submit"/>GO</button>
</form>
```

**p2.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "jag_db");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
    //$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
    $i=5001;
    $j="Chandigarh";
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO transtest (roll,city) VALUES(?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $i, $j);
    if(!$stmt->execute())
    {
        $mysqli->rollback();
        exit;
    }
    $sql20=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM transtest");
    $sql20->execute();
    $result20=$sql20->get_result();
    if($result20->num_rows>0)
    {
        while($rows20=$result20->fetch_object())
        {
            echo $rows20->sno . "    ----    " . $rows20->roll  . "    ----    " . $rows20->city . "<br>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $mysqli->rollback();
        exit;
    }
    $sql20->close();
    $mysqli->commit();
    $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="submit"/>GO</button>
</form>
```

First I start executing p1.php and immediately, I also start clicking the go button of p2.php another other browser tab.
Following are the results of p2.php when:

**p1.php is still executing**

[Image: p1.php is still executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD6BW.jpg)

**when p1.php has finished executing**

[Image: when p1.php has finished executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGcBi.jpg)

It is good to see that at the end, I get the accurate results but it is bad to see that even when one transaction is execute, another user is getting the wrong output. The second user should not be able to see anything when the p1.php is executing.

> Note: $mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
>   doesnt work in my current version of php. It says **Warning:
>   mysqli::begin_transaction(): This server version doesn't support 'READ
>   WRITE' and 'READ ONLY'. Minimum 5.6.5 is required**

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

for Mysql, automatic lock will be applied to the table when any of your operation written in your code is executed, so you are safe.

Comment: Hi, I am no asking about an operation. What I want is when I execute multiple SQL queries on a database, the tables should not be accessible by any user on any other connection.

Comment: it will automatically locks the table for any operation, so the other queries will not be executed till the current ones finish.